# Set focus to item in accordion list

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a list of Orders on a form that are displayed in an accordion, I have a button when pressed pops up a modal form where the user can input details of a new item to add to the order.  On the modal form, the user presses a button 'Add', the modal form closes and on the main form the new item is added to the accordion list.
The accordion list is made up of order items, each displays the item code, price and a few other things.  There is also a textbox on each accordion item for the user to update the quantity.  So I was wondering once a new item has been added is it possible to set the focus to the quantity textbox of this new accordion item.
I used ajax to call the AddNewItem method in the controller.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Order/AddOrderItem/" + orderId,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
        handleErrorMessages(result);
        var $orderItemsAccordion = $("#order-items-accordion");

        $orderItemsAccordion.append(result.HtmlViewResult);
        $("#order-drug-item-modal").modal("hide");
        },

        error: function(error) {
           alert('An error occurred when adding the Order item.');
        }

        });
```

Or is there a way I can get the index of this item, like an array index?
Or is it best when the call is made to the controller get the count of order items there and pass it back to the Javascript?

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, You can use the jQuery `.focus()` function

Comment: I know to use the .focus() function but I dont know how to get the correct index of the item in the accordion list so I know which one to set the focus to.  The index of the item that has just been added.  For example, if there were already 2 items on the form and a user enters a third, how to find out it's the third item so I can use    `$(".quantity")[2].focus()`

Comment: Well we cannot guess what your html is :) - but since you have a class name, and its the last item you added, then you can just use `$('.quantity').last().focus();`

Comment: Oh goodness...so simple!  Why didn't I think of that!!  It worked...thank you!! :)